# iOS: Visual format constraints are broken

Tags: ios, constraints, visual-format-language

I'm trying to lay a button over a map and constrain it to 10 points in from the left and 10 points up from the bottom. However, when I run it in simulator it tells me my constraints are broken. Here's my code. What am I missing?

```
_map = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
[self setView:_map];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.810166, -86.156708);

_loc = [[TCMLocationPoint alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord title:@"My Location" subtitle:@"My Subtitle"];
[_loc setParent:_map];
[_map addAnnotation:_loc];

MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 2000, 2000);
[_map setRegion:region animated:NO];

_directionsButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[_directionsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(getLocation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[_directionsButton setTitle:@"Get Directions" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_directionsButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 150.0, 25.0)];

[[self view] addSubview:_directionsButton];

NSDictionary *nameMap = @{@"button" : _directionsButton};
NSArray *horizontalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[button]-(>=0)-|"
                                                                                     options:0
                                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                                       views:nameMap];
[[self view] addConstraints:horizontalConstraints];
NSArray *verticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(>=0)-[button]-10-|"
                                                                                   options:0
                                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                                     views:nameMap];

[[self view] addConstraints:verticalConstraints];
```

Comment: Are you doing this in `loadView` or `viewDidLoad` or somewhere else?

Comment: I'm using viewDidLoad

Comment: Then, assuming you're using a NIB or storyboard, you should just add the map as a subview of `self.view` rather than replacing `self.view`, setting up the appropriate constraints for it, as well. See my revised answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. I'd set [`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) to `NO`.
2. You can probably simplify your VFL, too, and eliminate the `>=0` stuff. You can also set the width and height right in your VFL.
3. You also don't need to set the `frame`. Let the constraints set the width, height.
4. Unless you're doing this in `loadView`, I'd suggest you add the map as a subview rather than trying to set `self.view`.

Thus:

```
_map = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
_map.delegate = self;   // if you've implemented any `MKMapViewDelegate` methods, you should set your delegate
[_map setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addSubview:_map];
NSDictionary *views = @{@"map" : _map};
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[map]|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:views]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[map]|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:views]];

// do your stuff where you're adding your annotation here

_directionsButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[_directionsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(getLocation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[_directionsButton setTitle:@"Get Directions" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_directionsButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

[[self view] addSubview:_directionsButton];

NSDictionary *nameMap = @{@"button" : _directionsButton};

NSArray *horizontalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[button(150)]"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:nameMap];
[[self view] addConstraints:horizontalConstraints];

NSArray *verticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[button(25)]-10-|"
                                                                       options:0
                                                                       metrics:nil
                                                                         views:nameMap];
[[self view] addConstraints:verticalConstraints];
```

You might even want to set the priority for the width and height constraints to be less than 1000, that way if the font dictates that the button should be a little larger, you'll let it grow, e.g. `@"H:|-10-[button(150@500)]"` and `@"V:[button(25@500)]-10-|"`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the above, and I wound up with an exception: `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. MKMapView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'`

Comment: @LoneWolfPR Assuming you're doing this in `viewDidLoad`, don't just set `self.view` to the map, but rather add the map as a subview of `self.view`, set the appropriate constraints, and that error will go away.

Comment: adding map as subview fixed the error. The button shows up where it should, but now the map doesn't show up. EDIT-Sorry, just noticed the new constraints. Will do add that now.